# Python regex replacing whole match rather than group

Tags: python, regex

I have created [a regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/QfFaCY/7) to match a block within an Apache config file.
In the regex editor, it shows that it correctly matches the block and captures the group.
When I attempt to replace the group in Python, it replaces the whole match rather than the group.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

pattern = r"^(?:<Directory\s*\"\/var\/www\/html\">).*?(?:AllowOverride\s*)(None).*?(?:<\/Directory>)$"
repl = r"\g<1>All"

with open('httpd.conf', 'r') as io:
    string = io.read()
    o = re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=1, flags=re.M|re.S)
    print(o)
```

Output:

```xml
# Further relax access to the default document root:
NoneAll
```

Expected:

```xml
# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
...
    AllowOverride None
...
</Directory>
```

Comment: `(?:\s|.)*?` is just wrong, replace with `.*?` and add `flags=re.M|re.S`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Edited to reflect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `re.sub()` is working as designed and documented: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.sub. In particular,

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl.

That is, it's *supposed* to replace the entire match. `re.sub()` does not care about groups inside your pattern. It just cares about the entire pattern (ie. the entire match).

You can accomplish the same goal by passing a replacement *function*. This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re

pattern = r"^<Directory\s*\"\/var\/www\/html\">.*?</Directory>"
def repl(match):
    # A fancier version of this would do a regex replacement, but
    # regex replacement inside a regex replacement makes my
    # brain hurt.
    text = match.group(0)
    text = text.replace("AllowOverride None", "AllowOverride All")
    return text

with open('httpd.conf', 'r') as io:
    string = io.read()
    o = re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    print(o)
```

Limitations:

- it assumes that `<Directory>` sections cannot be nested
- it's not terribly flexible about the text it is replacing

Answer (score 1):

Like Greg stated, the issue was a fundamental misunderstanding of the replacement function on my part.

"That is, it's supposed to replace the entire match. re.sub() does not care about groups inside your pattern. It just cares about the entire pattern (ie. the entire match)."

I ended up changing my regular expression to:
`^(<Directory\s*\"\/var\/www\/html\">.*?AllowOverride\s*)(None)(.*?<\/Directory>)$`

and performing the replacement like so:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

pattern = r"^(<Directory\s*\"\/var\/www\/html\">.*?AllowOverride\s*)(None)(.*?<\/Directory>)$"
repl = r"\g<1>All\g<3>"

with open('httpd.conf', 'r') as io:
    string = io.read()
    o = re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=1, flags=re.M|re.S)
    print(o)
```